# Edit a properties text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file containing the properties for a virtual server running on my machine. I would like to be able to edit those properties from a GUI built with VB 2008. The Properties file is pre-generated with default values and I would like to change those values to fit my needs.

The Properties file is formatted as follows:

```
Item-One=ValueOne
Item-Two=ValueTwo
Item-Three=OtherLongValue
etc.
```

What I need is to be able to select the property based off it's name (Item-Two) and then remove the original value (which may be unknown) and place in my custom value. Values are String type.

I have already tried two suggestions, but neither achieve my goal.

```
Attempt1:
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(propName, System.IO.File.ReadAllText(propName).Replace("initial", "final"))

Attempt2:
Dim thefile As String = PropertyFileName
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(thefile)
lines(28) = "Item-Example=" + myValue
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(thefile, lines)
```

Number One does not work because it requires me to know the original value, which I do not.
Number Two "works" but often adds new lines instead of replacing the old.

Comment: Text files are not random access - you cant change a character here and there - you need to read it in, parse it, then save everything back when done.  That looks like an INI style file, so there are some WIN32 function to help parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a class I made.
 It is also documented which should help with inteliSense.
 Bellow I added some example of its usage.

---

## SettingManager.vb

```
''' <summary>
''' Manages Settings which can be loaded and saved to a file specified
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class SettingManager
    Private filePath As String
    Private prop As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a new SettingManager and loads settings from file specified.
    ''' If file specified doesnt exist, a new one is created upon save()
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filePath">Setting file to load</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Sub New(ByVal filePath As String)
        Me.filePath = filePath
        If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) Then
            Return
        End If
        Using reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
            Dim line As String
            line = reader.ReadLine()

            'Loop through the lines and add each setting to the dictionary: prop
            Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
                'Spit the line into setting name and value
                Dim tmp(2) As String
                tmp = line.Split("=")
                Me.AddSetting(tmp(0), tmp(1))
                line = reader.ReadLine()
            Loop
        End Using
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get value of specified setting if exists.
    ''' If setting doesnt exist, KeyNotFound exception is thrown
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="name">Name of setting</param>
    ''' <returns>Value of setting</returns>
    Function GetSetting(ByVal name As String) As String
        If (Not prop.ContainsKey(name)) Then
            Throw New KeyNotFoundException("Setting: " + name + " not found")
        End If
        Return prop(name)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds a new setting.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="name">Name of setting</param>
    ''' <param name="value">Value of setting</param>
    ''' <remarks>Save() function should be called to save changes</remarks>
    Sub AddSetting(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
        If (prop.ContainsKey(name)) Then
            prop(name) = value
        Else
            prop.Add(name, value)
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Saves settings to file. Any new settings added are also saved
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Sub Save()
        Using writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Me.prop
                writer.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value)
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

## How to use:

1. Create a new file in your project called `SettingManager.vb`
2. Copy the code above into it

## Example Usage

```
Dim sm As New SettingManager("settings.txt")

'Get Setting
Console.WriteLine(sm.GetSetting("Item-One")) 'Value-One

'Change setting
pm.AddSetting("Item-One", "different_value")
Console.WriteLine(sm.GetSetting("Item-One")) 'different_value

'Add new Setting
pm.AddSetting("name", "Krimson")
Console.WriteLine(sm.GetSetting("name")) 'Krimson

'Save any changes made
sm.Save()
```

---

Note: The code is not robust enough. For example if a value contains an `=`, errors might occur since there is no check implemented to prevent this. However, this should be a good starting point

Comment: Thank you very much, with a bit of tweaking this works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

A little Addition

```
          Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
                If line = Nothing OrElse line.Length = 0 OrElse line.StartsWith("#") Then
                    'Continue Do
                Else
                    'Spit the line into setting name and value
                    Dim tmp(2) As String
                    tmp = line.Split("=")
                    Me.AddSetting(tmp(0), tmp(1))

                End If
                line = reader.ReadLine()
            Loop
```

Comment: "A little Addition" to what? is your answer an addition to @Krimson answer? If so state it clearly, answers on SO can reorder due to score, its not like a time-based forum or a conversation.